# FCM notification is not working after network change (wifi to mobile network)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a notification android app with help of firebase (**FCM**). App is working fine, but problem is when I am changing its network state (like WIFI to mobile data) then notification is not coming or coming too late. i search many article but didn't get any proper solution, please help me, how should i handle this problem ?

Comment: You don't have any way to handle this. FCM should take care of this but it seems that you are hitting some particular case. If you can reproduce this please contact https://firebase.google.com/support/ with a bugreport from the affected device.

Comment: can you please share your fire base version? I am facing same issue